# Let G be a simple planar graph on 13 vertices. Prove that at least one of G and its complement G is not planar.

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Let G be a simple planar graph on 13 vertices. Prove that at least one of G and its
complement G is not planar.

Can we say that:
 e<=3n-6 , where n = number of vertices
$n(n-1)/2$ is the total number of edges  in graph.
Thus let's say that n = 5 , if we substitute it to $n(n-1)/2=e<=3n-6$ we will get that $10<=9$ which is not right. Actually we should substitude 13 i think to formula described before. From this point if G isn't planar , then G complement isn't planar as well? Is it possible to show it in this way?

Comment: This is a strange statement to prove. $G$ *is* planar by assumption. So, what we need to show is that $G$'s complement is *not* planar?

Comment: Hint: if $G$ has $e$ edges, how many edges does the complement of $G$ have?